Laravel 11: Handling exceptions in app - Reportable not working
I'm having trouble with the reportable function in Laravel 11, and I'm not sure what's wrong.
Here's the code I'm working with:
use App\Exceptions\UnauthorizedApi;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {

    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->reportable(function (UnauthorizedApi $e) {
            die ('SAF');
        });
    })->create();

I've set it up according to the documentation.
And here's the UnauthorizedApi exception class:
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class UnauthorizedApi extends Exception
{
    //
}

Any help would be appreciated.

Welcome to SO ... where are you throwing this Exception?

I throw it in When cookie havent auth_token, that I set when login.
abstract class ApiModel
{
abstract protected function setData(array $data): self;
private static function client()
{

    if (($token = request()->cookie('auth_token')) !== null) {
        return new Client([
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => "Bearer $token"
            ]
        ]);
    } else {

        throw new UnauthorizedApi;
    }
}

....
It throw this error but I want to do event on this error
